# cakephp routing issue after adding a plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0

I added CakeDC-Users plugin in app/plugins.

Now for http://example.com/ , if i click the home/index link, it wrongly redirects to http://example.com/users/posts/index , but it should be http://example.com/posts/index .

Why is the plugin 'users' always added before the respective controller?

If i delete the CakeDC-Users plugin from app/Plugin and delete that line `CakePlugin::loadAll();` from bootstrap.php then i get normal link/route

routes.php:

`Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'));`

How can i fix that problem addin CakeDC-Users plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the way how plugins are accessed. You can define your custom route this way

```
Router::connect('/posts', array('controller' => 'posts', 'plugin' => 'users'));
```

This will be done in app/Config/routes.php

if it is for link issues you will have to explicitly specify

```
echo $this->Html->link('link', array(
                                 'controller' => '', 
                                 'action' => '', 
                                 'plugin' => false)
                      );
```

But i would prefer custom routing.

For more info, you can always sneak into the [CookBook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#routes-configuration)

Comment: Do i have to explicitly write 'plugin'=>false in every link? I have this in routes.php , `Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'));`

Comment: @prime yes, if you don't define routes, you will have to explicitly define plugin => false.. It will be fine if you are outside your plugin, but once you navigate inside the plugin then those links will be at fault.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid adding 'plugin'=>false manually for all links?

Comment: @prime you can avoid that by using routes

Comment: How? Can you explain with example?

Comment: I have already give you an example in my answer. Also refer to the link. It will really help you understand routing concepts

Comment: Still no solution to avoid adding 'plugin'=>false manually for all links if I don't want to create xxx routes either ?